# PHP ftp_chdir - can't mask error

Tags: php, ftp

I have function below to check if specific item is directory or file:

```
private function isDir($dir)
{
    if ( @ftp_chdir($this->connected, $dir) === true )
    {
        ftp_chdir($this->connected, '..');
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It detects correctly but even if I put @ before error I always get the same error:

```
WARNING: [2] - ftp_chdir() [function.ftp-chdir]: CWD failed. "/someDIR/someFile.xls": directory not found.  in file: D:\www\testiranje\epg\classes\ftpClass.php - line 147
```

I know that error is more than expected, but that is the best way I figured out to detect if some item is dir or not ...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why not use is_dir function http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Comment: have no idea how to check if is directory on remote FTP? Is it possible?

Comment: look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554346/how-to-check-using-php-ftp-functionality-if-folder-exists-on-server-or-not

Comment: It works! But can't thick you for that :) You can post the answer and i will! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)  like :

```
is_dir('ftp://user:password@example.com/some/dir/path');
```

Comment: that is a solution, but it will need to open a new connection

Answer (score -2):

I think it can be suppresed, using this in your code - prior to the statement, that issuses the the Warning

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

Comment: Yes they can be suppressed but is it really useful? Warnings are a nice information source for finding mistakes in the code and I think your code shouldn't produce any warnings.

Comment: Furthermore I hope that you haven't any options for displaying errors set in a productive system.