# Return files tree from FTP

Tags: php, file, web-applications, ftp

I am trying to list files from an FTP server. I would like to get an array of sub-directories and files in them as a tree, as shown below:

```
folder1
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
folder2
       folder2a
               file1.txt
               file2.txt
               file.3txt
       folder2b
              file1.txt
```

Now my array will be something like

```
[folder1]=>array(file1.txt,file2.txt) 
[folder2]=>array([folder2a]=>array(file1.txt,file2txt,file3.txt)
[folder2b]=>array(file1.txt))
```

Note: the array above might not be the exact syntax but just to give an idea of what I am looking for. 
I tried ftp_nlist() but seems to only return the files and folders but not the files inside the sub-folders.
Here is a sample on how my code looks like

```
 // set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// get contents of the ftp directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

// output $contents
var_dump($contents);
```

With the above it only lists of folders and not files. Anyone with a good idea on how to go around this?
Thank you.

Comment: When you vote it down please let me know why.I am stuck and I need a better assistance. Is there a better way of doing this?Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ftp_nlist()` doesn't fetch files and directories recursively, it just returns all files and folders at the specified path. You could write a function to fetch the results in a recursive manner. Here is an example recursive function that someone wrote, which I found in the PHP **[ftp_nlist()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php)** documentation:

```
<?php 
/** 
 * ftpRecursiveFileListing 
 * 
 * Get a recursive listing of all files in all subfolders given an ftp handle and path 
 * 
 * @param resource $ftpConnection  the ftp connection handle 
 * @param string $path  the folder/directory path 
 * @return array $allFiles the list of files in the format: directory => $filename 
 * @author Niklas Berglund 
 * @author Vijay Mahrra 
 */ 
function ftpRecursiveFileListing($ftpConnection, $path) { 
    static $allFiles = array(); 
    $contents = ftp_nlist($ftpConnection, $path); 

    foreach($contents as $currentFile) { 
        // assuming its a folder if there's no dot in the name 
        if (strpos($currentFile, '.') === false) { 
            ftpRecursiveFileListing($ftpConnection, $currentFile); 
        } 
        $allFiles[$path][] = substr($currentFile, strlen($path) + 1); 
    } 
    return $allFiles; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Great!It works well for me. Thanks a lot. You have just introduced me to recursive!

Comment: Glad I could help, recursion is a very important concept in programming. :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me if I put a '.' or '/' in the $path field, it just continuously loops. Need to get everything from login directory, is that possible with this?

Comment: Didn't work for me. The function only returns the filenames from the start directory and does not return from child directories recursively.

Comment: I had the same issue with this not returning any child directories. Upon closer inspection, $currentFile yielded the following results: "./photos". The dot in the path obviously causing it to not do any recursive iterating. Make sure to change the if condition when using '.' as $path.

Comment: I ended up using the following method to check if the file is a directory or not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554346/how-to-check-using-php-ftp-functionality-if-folder-exists-on-server-or-not

Comment: Assuming directory names do not have dots in them is wrong. Better go with Ahmad Mnx answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
function remotedirectory($directory)
{
    global $ftp;
    $basedir = "/public_html";
    $files = ftp_nlist($ftp,$basedir.$directory);
    foreach($files as $key => $file)
    {
        if(is_dir("ftp://username:password@doamin/".$basedir.$directory."/".$file))
        {
            $arrfile[] = remotedirectory($directory."/".$file);
        }else{
            $arrfile[] = $directory.'/'.$file;
        }
    }
    return $arrfile;
}
```

Comment: Any drawbacks to this method (`is_dir`)? I have found this more reliable than assuming directory names without dots and also more stable than repeated `ftp_chdir` for directory checking, which silently times out after a while.