# Trouble finding the directory using FTP in php

Tags: php, ftp, directory

i wanna try this

link : [How to check using PHP FTP functionality if folder exists on server or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554346/how-to-check-using-php-ftp-functionality-if-folder-exists-on-server-or-not)
tell me if my code is right;

i cant seem to find the folder and it echoes the failed

sample ftp account is

user: admin@mywebsite.com

pass: name@pasword

ftp file root is : /home/mywebsite/public_html/admin

path folder i want to find is: public_html/admin/userfiles

i set the path ftp account path on the admin from cpanel

```
if(is_dir('ftp://admin@mywebsite.com:name@pasw0rd@mywebsite.com/userfiles'))
{
 echo 'found';
}
else
{
 echo 'failed';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some prerequisites to using 'ftp://` this way:

- The PHP directive `allow_url_fopen` must be set to true;
- The target server must support `passive ftp`

Assuming both of those things, your URL must be accurate. The convention is `ftp://name:password@server.example.com/folder`. Your URL appears to have a spurious `:name@` in it.

```
ftp://admin@mywebsite.com:name@pasw0rd@mywebsite.com/userfiles'
                         ^^^^^^
```

Comment: He said the password was: name@pasw0rd

Comment: @Marijke, so he did, but the name/password string looks decidedly suspect. It has to be worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

FTP function checks if a directory exists

```
<?php
function ftp_is_dir( $dir ) {
    global $ftpcon;
    // get current directory
    $original_directory = ftp_pwd( $ftpcon );
    // test if you can change directory to $dir
    // suppress errors in case $dir is not a file or not a directory
    if ( @ftp_chdir( $ftpcon, $dir ) ) {
        // If it is a directory, then change the directory back to the original directory
        ftp_chdir( $ftpcon, $original_directory );
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }        
} 
?>
```